# Toggling android checkbox preference based on a condition

Tags: android

I have a need where when I click on a checkboxpreference it should show a dialog when a condition is true and toggle (check or uncheck) when the condition is false. How do I implement it? I tried playing with both OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener and OnPreferenceClickListener (see pseudocode below). When the condition is true the dialog shows up but the checkboxpreference gets toggled as well - how to avoid it?

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) 
{
     if(key.equals("mykey"))
      {
          if(condition)
          {
              showDialog(this);
              return;
          }
          else
         {
           //logic to process prefernce change
         }


      }
}
```

This is another thing I tried using preferenceclicklistener

```
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) 
  {

   if(preference.getKey().equals("mykey"))
    {
        if(condition)
        {
            showDialog(this);
            //returning true below means i have handled the click and it should not do anything
            // else. Why is checkboxpreference getting toggled?
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Need to extend checkboxpreference and override onclick() to do this.